# Extracting draw() method on a separate loop (PApplet as a JADE Agent)

Tags: java, multithreading, processing, agents-jade

I am creating a JADE-based agent system on Java, and I want to use Processing for visualizing these agents. Now the JADE framework runs on it's own, and a Processing `PApplet` is instantiated as one of the agents, which is a singleton.

Every time one of the (other types of) agents change, they call the `redraw()` method of the PApplet. The problem is, the PApplet doesn't call it's `draw()` method, since it's not running on it's own thread.

How do I fix this?

EDIT:

```
public class Manager extends Agent{
        //The Agent object that runs as a separate thread under JADE framework.
        protected void setup(){
                ...
                javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new VisualizerThreadRunnable(this));
                ...
        }
}
class VisualizerThreadRunnable implements Runnable {
        public VisualizerThreadRunnable(Manager m){
                  ...
        }
        public void run(){
                System.out.println("visualizer being launched...");
                Visualizer visualizer = new Visualizer(manager);
                visualizer.setVisible(true);
        }
}

public class Visualizer extends PApplet {
        //from examples on http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/
        public Visualizer(Manager m){
                this.m = m;
                ...
        }
        public void setup() {
                size(200,200);
                background(0);
        }

        public void draw() {
                stroke(255);
                if (mousePressed) {
                        line(mouseX,mouseY,pmouseX,pmouseY);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: can you post a bit of code ? Are you initializing the PApplet instance ? If so how ? My rough guess is PApplet's thread isn't started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the visualizer thread you also need to initialize the PApplet using init():

```
 public void run(){
                System.out.println("visualizer being launched...");
                Visualizer visualizer = new Visualizer(manager);
                visualizer.init();//This is pretty important
                visualizer.setVisible(true);
        }
```

For more information checkout [PApplet's javadocs](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html).

This should solve the Processing side of the problem. I've never used Jade before, 
so I don't know if the thread will stay on. Do check if that happens, if not maybe you should keep that thread running.

Comment: I think you are right - I missed that because this is an untested paradigm for Processing - all examples on net point at Processing managing other processes as threads. Anyway I shifted to plain Java `swing` GUI after realizing that my requirements better suited there. (Menus etc).

Comment: No worries. If it's just a few lines or simple graphics, it makes sense to use Swing's Graphics' related classes. Now you also know how to integrate Processing wit swing just in case and as a side note, you can use Processing's get() function to grab a 'screenshot' of the sketch as an PImage which using [getNative()](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PImage.html#getNative()) is converted to a BufferedImage...but this is a hacky workaround